# XMl Search and filter in windows phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
  <player>
    <playerId>1234</playerId>
    <playerName>ABCD</playerName>

   <line>
      <studentId>5612</studentId>
      <studentName>WXYZ</studentName>
   </line>

  </player>
</root>
```

above shown is my XML,

I have to show "studentName" from XML with filter "playername"
so, how should I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Well how far have you got so far? I would look into LINQ to XML - it's easy to convert that XML document into a `List<Player>` where `Player` has the appropriate properties.

Comment: I know but I want only "studentName" with respect to "playerName".....
thanks

Comment: That doesn't tell us anything about how far you've got. Basically this isn't terribly hard, but if we just give you the code you won't learn much. You should look into LINQ to XML, try it for yourself, and then post a *specific* question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ2XML. Try this:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <player>
    <playerId>1234</playerId>
    <playerName>ABCD</playerName>

   <line>
      <studentId>5612</studentId>
      <studentName>WXYZ</studentName>
   </line>

  </player>
</root>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

string studentName = (string)doc.Descendants("player")
               .Where(p => (string)p.Element("playerName") == "ABCD")
               .Descendants("studentName").First();
```

Comment: but "studentname" is not Descendants in the final line

Comment: @VirajShah, What you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a chance for some LINQ to XML

See refs [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387041.aspx) and [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=564) for examples.